# как починить такую ошибку?

Tags: java, android

У меня завис ноут, после перезагрузки открыл студию и при загрузке проекта вывалилась такая ошибка :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/aleksey/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Что это означает подскажите? Как это можно починить?

Вот скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот еще скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ниже в ошибке ничего нет?.. Возможно студия не сохранила какие-то изменения в XML файлах, они стали невалидные вот она и ругается.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать build clean и сбилдить завново

Comment: @Y.Pashkov а как сделать build clean?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko У вас на скриншоте, вкладка build (справа от Refactor, слева от Run). Так вот build-> clean project, и попробуйте запустить еще раз.

Comment: @Y.Pashkov спасибо! Все заработало))